# neo4j - return node vs part of a node preformance

Tags: neo4j

I have been wondering if there is a performance difference between those two queries:

1. `Match (n:User {id: "bla"}) return n`
2. `Match (n:User {id: "bla"") return n.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how you invoke your Cypher statement. If you emit the cypher statement remotely via http (or bolt in 3.0) returning the node will add all its properties to the response. Returning a single property causes less amount of data transferred over the network.

When firing the cypher statement in embedded mode using `GraphDatabaseService.execute()` returning nodes only might be cheaper since you get back just the nodes. Upon first access of a property the property chain will be loaded lazily.